# unprotect cells in excel worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to change cell content in protected sheet, but get password fault stating Caps Lock is on.
 Code is as follows:

```
        'Change Best Peak Flow and Date Achieved

        ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=asthma
        If Range("R7").Value > Range("F7").Value Then
            Range("R7").Select
            Selection.Copy
            Range("F7").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
            Range("K7") = Date
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=asthma, DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Is `asthma` the name of a variable containing the password, or is it the password itself that's missing a pair of quotes?

Comment: asthma is the password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've forgotten to put a pair of quotes around `asthma` to make it a string literal, so VBA interprets it as the name of a variable. Since this variable hasn't been declared, its value is an empty string.

You can avoid errors like this by putting `Option Explicit` at the start of each module, so the VBA editor will give an error when you try to use an undeclared variable.

Comment: Thank you jsheeran, it works a treat with the quotes, your help was much appreciated.